# $\phi\in(C([0,m]))^*,|\phi(f)|\leq\lVert f\rVert_\infty,\phi(1)=1\implies \phi(\mbox{id})\in\mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $C([0,m])$ be the algebra of all complex-valued continuous function on $[0,m]$, $\phi:C([0,m])\rightarrow\mathbb C$ a linear functional such that $|\phi(f)|\leq\lVert f\rVert_\infty$ and $\phi(\unicode{x1D7D9}_{[0,m]})=1$, and $\
> I(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,m]$. Show that $\phi(I)\in\mathbb R$ by considering $I+ic\unicode{x1D7D9}_{[0,m]}$, $c\in\mathbb R$.

I tried to show that $|\phi(I)-\Re\phi(I)|=0$ by using the inequlity, but failed. Any hints on how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(id)=a+ib$ with $a,b \in \mathbb R$. Then we have

$|a+ib+ic| \leq \|id+ic1_{[0,m]}\|_{\infty}\leq \sqrt {m^{2}+c^{2}}$. Hence, $a^{2}+(b+c)^{2} \leq m^{2}+c^{2}$. This is true for all $c \in \mathbb R$.Take $c=nb$ to get $a^{2}+(n+1)^{2}b^{2}\leq m^{2}+n^{2}b^{2}$. Can you see that this cannot hold for large $n$ unless $b=0$?